# Operation of pickle in Blender 2.56

Tags: python-3.x, blender-2.50

I am using pySerial to get data from an Arduino (micro-controller).

The data are stored in a pickle file. It worked fine with Blender 2.49 (python 2.7).

Now, shifting to Blender 2.56 (python 3.2), I get the following error:

```
f=open('abc.dat','r')

with serial.Serial('COM31',9600) as port :
    for i in range(0, 10):
            x = port.read(size=1)
            print(int(x))
            y=pickle.load(f)
            f.close()
            f=open('abc.dat','w')
            y.append(i)                        
            pickle.dump(y,f)
            f.close()

port.close()

error:
Python script error from controller "Python Script#CONTR#1":
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "256script1.py", line 18, in <module>
    f.close()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\BLENDE~1\Blender\2.54\python\lib\pickle.py", line 1365, in l
oad
    encoding=encoding, errors=errors).load()
ValueError: read() from the underlying stream did notreturn bytes

Blender Game Engine Finished
```

Are there any operational changes in the use of `pickle`?

Comment: You are supposed to accept the best answer to your questions. Please accept some answers. It's really annoying to spend time to answer questions and then you get nothing for it.

Comment: i m really sorry. but was unaware of such a thing..
hw m i supossed to do the same?

Comment: You select the checkbox besides the best answer. Please read the FAQ. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the file in text mode, but for pickles it should be in binary mode. In Python 2 this doesn't matter (Except on Windows), but in Python 3 it does.

It should be

```
f=open('abc.dat','rb')
```